# Blossom and downloading file from server

Tags: spring-mvc, download, magnolia

I'm trying to download file generated on server. One of them are placed on the disc while some others are downloaded from external webservice as base64 decoded byte[].

But when I do 
FileCopyUtils.copy(new FileInputStream(dFile), response.getOutputStream());

the downloaded file is corrupted because it contains html code of current page. Is there any 'special' way of downloading file with Blossom ?

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really sure what you are trying to do. So you saying that you take file `dFile` and just dump it to output stream you obtained from `HttpServletResponse`?

There is multitude of reasons why it doesn't work. Your component is probably inside of some page, so chances are high that there is already something written the output stream. Also you have not mentioned anywhere whether or not did you set the response headers correctly to indicate that you are sending file back.
IMO the easiest way to go around it is to create a custom servlet, place it in the chain along other servlets and send file from there rather than sending it from the component. Have a look at for example [DamDownloadServlet](http://git.magnolia-cms.com/gitweb/?p=modules/dam.git;a=blob;f=magnolia-dam-core/src/main/java/info/magnolia/dam/core/download/DamDownloadServlet.java;h=a96dae2b00af96bea65d344aef681fa7a0b6d049;hb=HEAD), specially its `handleResourceRequest ()` method.

HTH,
Jan

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your response. This could be hard to do because I need to fill the page with some data as well as download the file. So I need current component to be called. You are right - this is the blossom component and it's placed inside other page. So there is something at the output stream.

And this is my code. As you can see, I'm setting the right ContentType.

```
ServletContext context = RequestContextUtils.getWebApplicationContext(request).getServletContext();
            String mimetype = context.getMimeType(dFile.getAbsolutePath());
            response.setContentType(mimetype != null ? mimetype : "application/pdf");
            response.setContentLength(new Long(dFile.length()).intValue());
            response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\""+dFile.getName()+"\"");
            try {
                FileCopyUtils.copy(new FileInputStream(dFile), response.getOutputStream());
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                logger.error(e);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                logger.error(e);
            }
```

Regards
Jan

Comment: what you do there will just return pdf, not write something in the page and send the file. And it will work only if nothing was committed on the response yet. To ensure nothing is committed, you can use feature in blossom to pre-execute your model so it's called before rendering starts you can try to suppress everything else.